# lightning:input type="date" not binding with my object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm currently creating a Lightning Component for a custom object in SalesForce, for some reason the data is not binding to this input. Even when I select a date from the date picker nothing shows up on the input field. I have read/write access to the field as I see it in a previous VF page I created for this object. All other fields are binding correctly, just not the dates.

```
<force:recordData aura:id="applicantRecord" targetRecord="{!v.applicant}" targetFields="{!v.applicantFields}" targetError="{!v.error}" layoutType="FULL" mode="EDIT"/>

<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Applicant__c">
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <lightning:input label="First Name" value="{!v.applicantFields.FirstName__c}"/>
        <lightning:input label="Last Name" value="{!v.applicantFields.LastName__c}"/>
        <lightning:input type="email" label="Email" value="{!v.applicantFields.Email__c}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="PlacementState__c" value="{!v.applicantFields.PlacementState__c}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Ref1" checked="{!v.applicantFields.Reference1__c}" labelClass="uiLabel-top"/>
        <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Ref2" checked="{!v.applicantFields.Reference2__c}"/>
        <lightning:input label="Bill Rate" value="{!v.applicantFields.BillRate__c}"/>
        <lightning:input label="Pay Rate" value="{!v.applicantFields.PayRate__c}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <lightning:input type="date" label="Start Date" value="{!v.applicantFields.StartDate__c}"/>
        <lightning:input type="date" label="End Date" value="{!v.applicantFields.EndDate__c}"/>
    </div>
    <lightning:button label="Save" onclick="{!c.save}"/>
    <div>
        {!v.error}
    </div>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Comment: You should use `lightning:inputField` within a `lightning:recordEditForm` to create editable fields. Any specific reason why you are using `lightning:input`?

Comment: There was no specific reason, but it still doesn't bind on lightning:inputField either.

Comment: Do you have these fields mentioned in `applicantFields`? You may like to verify it there.

Comment: layout mode is FULL isn't that supposed to include all Fields?

Comment: Well, that made me want to check my Layout for Applicant. Sure enough those dates were not on it. Interested "gotcha" moment that SalesForce doesn't discuss.

Comment: You figured it out. Had missed that you have used layout here. So that's the case, if you are using a layout type (and not fields), then you should verify if the fields are present on the layout or not. It's mentioned in the [*documentation*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/specification) -- *Name of the layout to query, which determines the **fields** included.*

Comment: You should answer your question and mark that as resolved, so anyone coming across this knows what was the issue and that it helps anyone with same scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was two things.

1. As Jayant pointed out, lightning:inputField should be used rather than lightning:input.
2. layoutType=FULL still requires the fields to be on the Page Layout of the object otherwise the data won't show when it's pulled with Lightning Data Service.